# Convert string property value to base64 on serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, base64

Does anyone know if its possible to convert some of the values in a class to Base64 when you serialize the object?  I need a way to mark a property to indicate that it needs to be exported as Base64.  For example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyFoo {
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    [ExportThisValueAsBase64]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public void WriteJSON(MyFoo myFoo) {
    var contentsToWriteToFile = SerializeObject(myFoo, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

The expected output would then be:

```
{ "Value1": "A String", "Value2": base64encodedvalue }
```

I would also need a way to read the values back in from base64 to the string property in the class.

Comment: Create a custom JsonConverter and tag the property.

Answer (score 7):

What I did in the end was, as advised in the comments, to create a `JsonConverter`

```
internal class CustomBase64Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {                
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((Convert.FromBase64String((string)reader.Value)));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {                
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)value)));
    }           
}
```

Now on any of my properties I can just add the heading

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomBase64Converter))]
```