# Convert string property value to base64 on serialization For ASP.NET Core 3.0+

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization, base64, system.text.json

I am trying to encode selected `string`-valued properties as Base64 when serializing to JSON, as shown in the following question:

*[Convert string property value to base64 on serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032651/convert-string-property-value-to-base64-on-serialization)*

But I'm using System.Text.Json since, with the introduction of ASP.NET Core 3.0, the default JSON serializer has been changed from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json.

How can the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46040273/3744182) by [Chris Richardson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5435610/chris-richardson) be modified to work with System.Text.Json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following [custom `JsonConverter<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#sample-basic-converter):

```
public class Base64EncodedStringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.GetBytesFromBase64());

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteBase64StringValue(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
}
```

Then apply it to your model as follows:

```
public class MyFoo 
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(Base64EncodedStringConverter))] // Fully qualified attribute name used for clarity
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- `System.Text.Json` has built-in support for reading and writing byte arrays as Base64 so manually encoding and decoding the Base64 is not required.
- If you don't want to allow null string values, override [`JsonConverter<T>.HandleNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.handlenull?view=net-5.0) to return `true` and throw exceptions as required from `Read()` and `Write()` (.NET 5 and later only).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nu2My7).