# Are there any methods to automatically convert strings inside JSON response to BASE64?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, base64

I'm returning objects as JSON results from my `APIController` inside an ASP.NET MVC web-API.

To convert objects to JSON results I use the below syntax:

```
return Ok(new WebServiceResult(...));
```

1. Are there any methods to convert strings automatically to BASE64 encoding during object to JSON conversions?
2. Can OK handle non-English characters during JSON conversions and avoid failure to decode that string on other platforms (I mean does it support encodings like UTF-8 or does it handle escape characters that reside inside the contents which are going to be converted such as `{` character or `:` character)?

Comment: Why do you want to convert *strings* into base64? Base64 is designed to encode *binary* data as text. JSON can represent all Unicode text with no problems.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?  It wouldn't be much of a JSON serializer if it couldn't serialize strings with double quotes, brackets, etc.

Comment: As explained in its [Serialization Guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#PrimitiveTypes), Json.NET (and also System.Text.Json) will automatically encode any `byte []` property as a Base64 string. If your string represents binary data you could just leave it as `byte []` and let Json.NET encode it as Base64 for you.

Comment: But if you really have a string you must encode as Base64 for some reason, you will have to apply a custom converter. See [Convert string property value to base64 on serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46040273/3744182), which looks to be a duplicate.

Comment: Also, if your JSON contains non-ASCII characters that are getting mangled during transmission (due to encoding inconsistencies or bugs or whatever), you can force them to be escaped by setting `JsonSerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii` as shown in [How to serialize special characters with JsonSerializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60580155/3744182) which might also be a duplicate, depending on your actual problem.